# Python - XML Parsing - Accessing values of different descendants of the same element

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I am trying to parse an Xml file using Python. My file has a structure similar to the below:

```
<dataset>
  <dataTable id = 123>
      <name> Name1 </name>
      <attributeList>
          <attribute id = 1>
               <measurement>
                  <textDomain>
                     <definition>User defined. </definition>
                  </textDomain>
               </measurement>
          </attribute>
          <attribute id = 2>
               <measurement>
                  <dateTime>
                     <formatString>MM-YYYY </formatString>
                  </dateTime>
               </measurement>
          </attribute>
      </attributeList>
</dataTable>
<dataTable id = 456>
    <name> Name8 </name>
    <attributeList>
        <attribute id = 3>
             <measurement>
                <unit>
                   <standardUnit>degree</standardUnit>
                </unit>
             </measurement>
        </attribute>
   </attributeList>
 </dataTable>
</dataset>
```

I want to extract the text ("User defined.", "MM-YYYY", "degree") inside the `<measurement>` tag. The `<measurement>` tag has different descendants for each `<attribute>`. How do I extract the text in this case?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a wildcard to get the child of the  *measurement* tag and any child of that child:

```
import lxml.etree as et

xml = et.parse("in.xml")

print(xml.xpath("//attributeList//measurement/*/*/text()"))
```

Which gives you:

```
['User defined.', 'MM-YYYY ', 'degree']
```

You could be explicit and pulling the first child:

```
 xml.xpath("//attributeList//measurement/*[1]/*[1]/text()")
```

But the fact there is only one child it would make no differene.